# Is there any way set cocoapods command line argument in podfile?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Every time run cocoapods, i will type a long command line, for example:

```
pod install --verbose --repo-update ----project-directory=xxxx
```

Is there any way i can write `--verbose --repo-update ----project-directory=xxxx` to podfile or any other cocoapods config file, so i can use `pod install` replace it but do the same work.
Or Is there any way auto run a shell when pod install

Comment: Nope. There is no provided by cocoapods for command line argument in pod file. You have to to write command every time when you need.

Comment: OK,Thanks, but Is there any way auto run a shell when pod install ?

Comment: You can use bash command line aliases. Just write them in .bash_profile